# Failed to build wheel command errored out with exit status 1? i have updated system tools and everything see below for cmd

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-wheel, python.net

I can't install python net everything in previous solutions I have followed through and it still doesn't work.
I have tried everything. Do I need to uninstall python and do it again?

pip install pyhtonnet
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyhtonnet (from versions: none)
    ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyhtonnet

```
C:\Users\vishv>pip install pythonnet
Collecting pythonnet
Using cached pythonnet-2.4.0.tar.gz (1.8 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pythonnet
Building wheel for pythonnet (setup.py) ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-qw1gpb32'
cwd: C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet
Complete output (69 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
Checking for updates from https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/.
Currently running NuGet.exe 4.1.0.
Updating NuGet.exe to 5.4.0.
Update successful.
Cannot find the specified version of msbuild: '14'
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '4.0' from 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319'.
Restoring NuGet package NUnit.3.7.1.
Restoring NuGet package NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0.
Restoring NuGet package UnmanagedExports.1.2.7.
Adding package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0' to folder 'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\packages'
Adding package 'NUnit.3.7.1' to folder 'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\packages'
Adding package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder 'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\packages'
Added package 'UnmanagedExports.1.2.7' to folder 'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\packages'
Added package 'NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.7.0' to folder 'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\packages'
Added package 'NUnit.3.7.1' to folder 'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\packages'

NuGet Config files used:
C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

Feeds used:
C:\Users\vishv.nuget\packages
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Installed:
3 package(s) to packages.config projects
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tools\geninterop\geninterop.py", line 24, in
from pycparser import c_ast, c_parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycparser'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\setup.py", line 623, in
setup(
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools_init_.py", line 144, in setup
return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\setup.py", line 610, in run
return bdist_wheel.bdist_wheel.run(self)
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
self.run_command('build')
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 340, in run
self.build_extensions()
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 449, in build_extensions
self._build_extensions_serial()
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 474, in _build_extensions_serial
self.build_extension(ext)
File "C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\setup.py", line 298, in build_extension
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, geninterop, interop_file])
File "c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe', 'tools\geninterop\geninterop.py', 'src\runtime\interop38.cs']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonnet
Running setup.py clean for pythonnet
Failed to build pythonnet
Installing collected packages: pythonnet
Running setup.py install for pythonnet ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h9hrt2n6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\pythonnet'
cwd: C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet
Complete output (6 lines):
usage: setup.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
or: setup.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
or: setup.py --help-commands
or: setup.py cmd --help

error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\vishv\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\setup.py'"'"'; file='"'"'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pwmwkrlc\pythonnet\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(file);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\vishv\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-h9hrt2n6\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing python 3.7 instead of 3.8? I just ran into a similar error with 3.8 but no problems with 3.7 (and upgraded pip and setuptools). Seems like 3.8. will only work with pythonnet version >= 2.5